# How can I get the name of a chosen optimizer in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch, tensorboard

I'm trying different optimizers to compare performance and as part of this, I'm logging the results using TensorBoard.

I've set up SummaryWriter output to include details such as the model used and learning rate.

```
writer = SummaryWriter(comment=f"_{base_model}_{lr}")
```

I would like it to also dynamically include the name of the optimizer, but there doesn't seem to be a built-in way to get the name of the selected optimizer.

Printing the optimizer does return its name. However, it's bundled with parameter information so not ideal for logging.

```
>>> print(optimizer)

Adam (
Parameter Group 0
    amsgrad: False
    betas: (0.9, 0.999)
    eps: 1e-08
    lr: 0.001
    weight_decay: 0
)
```

Is there a way I can get only the name of the optimizer without having to parse this output?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the PyTorch [source code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/optim/optimizer.py) for the base class for all optimizers, it's clear that as part of this print statement, the optimizer's class name is accessed.

So if the same method of accessing the class name is used in the print statement, then only the optimizer's name is printed:

```
>>> print(optimizer.__class__.__name__)

Adam
```

Integrating with the rest of the logging, the log name contains the required information:

```
writer = SummaryWriter(comment=f"_{base_model}_{optimizer.__class__.__name__}_{lr}")
```